# Processing pandas dataframe with variable delimiter and row length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tedious csv file with the following format

```
HELLO 1000 db1 3.88

HELLO 10 db123456 3.8899949

HELLO repository 10.0000

HELLO rep 001 0.001
```

Basically, the first four characters are always constant, while names are in different length and different separators

(for example, "1000 db1"), and final values are all float numbers but again in different formats/lengths.

What I would like is to be able to read columns as

```
constant name value

HELLO     .....    ....
```

I have looked for a solution but can't figure out. Initially, I was trying

`df.map(lambda x: x[...])`

to cut the last values but it does not work as the last values do not always have the same length.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you want. Perhaps you can have some sample input/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to split the CSV into three columns. You can use `re` module for the task (if `file.csv` is in the format as you describe in your question):

```
import re

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    df = pd.DataFrame(re.findall(r'([^\s]+)\s(.*)\s(.+)', f_in.read()), columns=['constant', 'name', 'value'])

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  constant         name      value
0    HELLO     1000 db1       3.88
1    HELLO  10 db123456  3.8899949
2    HELLO   repository    10.0000
3    HELLO      rep 001      0.001
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, this look exactly was I was looking for, thanks so much. I don't know re very well, could you help me understand the special character combination you've used?

Comment: @FrancescoGentile It's regular expression, super useful for dealing with text. I made [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eSVL42/1) - there's explanation of this regular expression on the right side. Basically I try to find three groups - the middle group should be the largest one.

Comment: Thanks so much Andrej, this is very useful and clear. One last question: why did you say the middle group (name) should be the largest? To my understanding your re expression says to take as middle group anything between the first whitespace and the last one, no matter what is there. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: @FrancescoGentile Yes, I meant the middle group should be largest, in the sense anything between first whitespace and last whitespace.

Comment: Perfect thanks again @Andrej. One little remark, as I think the example I provided was little bit confusing: my csv file actually doesn't have empty lines but newline at the end of each line, thus the second \s would take this \n. I made it working by using      ([^\s]+)[ ](.*)[ ](.+)    instead, so it looks for first and second white space and not other /s characters...